# Getting 'command not found' when running apt-get in unix

Tags: unix, command, apt-get

I am trying to instal daemon on Unix via the apt-get command. When I run the command

```
apt-get install daemon
```

I get

```
apt-get: command not found
```

Does anyone have nay ideas about how to fix this.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: are u sure that your distribution uses apt to install programms ?

Answer (score 0):

`apt-get` is not on OS X by default.  However, you can tweak it a little bit by using [Fink](http://www.finkproject.org/) so that you get the Debian packages.

Comment: I would suggest [homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/) over fink or macports.

Comment: Is there no existing tool on OSX that can accomplish the installation I'm attempting?